# Why are automatically inserted form event handlers different, depending on how they've been created?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, event-handling

I've noticed the form event handlers in an application I'm working on has differing object references: some of them are `Me.<event>` and some of them are `MyBase.<event>`. After a bit of playing around I've found that events created from the property window in the designer are given the `MyBase` reference, whereas events created by selecting them in the code window are given the `Me` reference.

I've [read up](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20fy88e0.aspx) on the differences between these two references, but that doesn't really shed any light on why one may be used rather than the other in these cases. So, should I be concerned about my form event handlers having differing references? And if so, which one *should* I be using?

Comment: Does this happen in any particular version of Visual Studio?

Comment: @roryap Well I'm using VS2013 Express now, but the application was originally created in VS2010.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Me` and `MyBase` do have different meanings, but when you are talking about event handlers, they can be used interchangeably.

`MyBase` is used when you want to reference a member from your base class.  This is useful when your derived class `Overrides` some member from your base class, but you want to specifically call the base class's implementation of that member rather than your own.  For instance:

```
Public Class MyBaseClass
    Public Overridable Sub DoWork()
        Console.WriteLine("Base")
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class MyDerivedClass
    Inherits MyBaseClass

    Public Overrides Sub DoWork()
        Console.WriteLine("Derived")
    End Sub

    Public Sub Test()
        Me.DoWork()
        MyBase.DoWork()
    End Sub
End Class
```

When the `MyDerivedClass.Test` method is called, the above example will output the following:

```
Derived
Base
```

So clearly, `Me` and `MyBase` mean two different things.  However, when it comes to events, there is no way, in VB.NET, for a derived class to override an event that was defined by its base class.  In fact, there's no way for a derived class to shadow an event, either.  If the base class defines an event, all classes that derive from it *must* have that event exactly as it is defined in the base class.

Since that is the case, when you define an event handler in a derived class, it doesn't matter whether you say `Handles Me.MyEvent` or `Handles MyBase.MyEvent`.  The event has to be the same in both classes, so the distinction is meaningless.  I suppose you could say that using `MyBase` is more *specific*, but I think that most people would agree that the amount of clarity that always using `MyBase`, where possible, would add to the code would be trivial.

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you. I'm still curious as to whether there's a specific reason for VB to create them differently from different places, but I guess since there's no effective difference when they're used as event handlers, it may well just be an unintentional anomaly.

Comment: My guess would be that it's just an oversight by the VS developers.  Probably different teams working on it resulting in different behaviors which never became an issue because of what Steven pointed out.

Comment: @roryap That's what I was thinking. Although it's possible this could contribute to misconceptions about the interchangeability of the two keywords, so it would certainly be better if they were consistent.